# AssertionError: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> on df['2017-10-10':'2017-10-25']

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am having trouble following a tutorial online. I have a Pandas dataframe as such:

```
df.head(5)

                                                user_id_doc  ...  document_version
created_at_doc                                               ...                  
2017-06-20 23:12:57+00:00  ab23fae164e34af0a1ad1423ce9fd9f0  ...               NaN
2017-06-20 23:16:04+00:00  15a84e8951254011b47412fa4e8f65b8  ...               NaN
2017-06-20 17:59:49+00:00  ffb82fda52b041e4b9af9cb4ef298c85  ...               NaN
2017-06-20 17:59:38+00:00  bd4a8b3e3601427e88aa1d9eab9f4290  ...               NaN
2017-06-20 18:08:09+00:00  f52ad1c7e69543a9940c3e7f8ed28a39  ...               NaN
```

The remaining columns are not relevant per this particular case. I am trying to take a look at a particular range of data (the first column of the dataframe), and the code I'm following puts it like this:

```
df['2017-10-10':'2017-10-25']
```

However, when I try to run this code it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../Python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3007, in __getitem__
    return self._slice(indexer, axis=0)
  File ".../Python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3809, in _slice
    assert isinstance(slobj, slice), type(slobj)
AssertionError: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

How can I fix this? Should I somewhat parse the dates so that they only include the date and not the time? And if so, could you help point me out in the right direction?

Thanks,
Tania

Comment: It should be `df.loc['2017-10-10':'2017-10-25']`.

Comment: It is indeed! Thank you very much :)